# Create operation like from JpaRepository, but using several fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

As I know - when I use a `JpaRepository<T, Integer>` method called `getOne(Integer id)` - I won't get an object, I'll get olny "link" to it in my database.
But I need to do this operation with TWO or more field, for example: `getOne(Integer id, String name)`.
In other words I need to get a link to object by two fields. How it can be done?
Can I use `@Query` or any specifical method signature? Thank you!

Comment: You can always use a classic SELECT. ;)

Comment: Just define your own `getByField1ANdField2` method.

Comment: @M.Deinum are you sure that it will be only reference, but not an object like getting one from "findByField1AndField2"?

Comment: Go check this, it is worth reading. To answer your questions, I am not even sure you will keep the same behavior. I am not sure... Is it really important for you to do Lazy-loading when fetching your Entity ?

Comment: I'm quite sure as that is the difference between `get` and `find`. That beind said, if you already pass the id, why the second field?

Comment: @M.Deinum because there are two entities, which have relation.

Comment: @M.Deinum so I need to check a restaurant by its "id" field and by user's "id" field, but I don't want to do "select" operation

Comment: @M.Deinum User is an owner of several Restaurants, there are OneToMany and ManyToOne annotations

Comment: If you don't do a select, then what is the point of the check as you aren't checking anything.

Comment: if the restaurant with those IDs doesn't exist - I'll get NPE (instead of a reference that method will return "null"). that is my checking

Answer (score 0):

Declare a method in your repository with a name

```
ObjectName findByIdAndName(Integer id, String name);
```

and JPA will implement it for you. Just make sure you are naming the method as I suggested.

You can also write a native query with both of your fields in `WHERE` clause. But the first method is better and more compact for a simple task like this.